# Boost serialization and file IO is extremely slow

Tags: c++, file-io, visual-studio-2012, boost-serialization

I am making a game and have a resource file format for loading 3d models, with textures and meshes etc defined like this:

```
/* PackageHeader definition */
    struct PackageHeader
    {
        std::string mSignature;
        uint8_t mMajorVersion;
        uint8_t mMinorVersion;


        PackageHeader();
    };

    /* PackageMesh definition */
    struct PackageMesh
    {
        std::vector<Vec3> mVertexData;
        std::vector<Vec3> mNormalData;
        std::vector<Vec2> mTexCoordsData;
        std::vector<uint32_t> mIndiceData;
        uint16_t mMaterialIndex;
        bool mHasMaterial;


        PackageMesh();
    };

    /* PackageTexture definition */
    struct PackageTexture
    {
        std::string mName;
        std::vector<uint8_t> mTextureData;
        uint32_t mTextureWidth;         // width/height in pixels
        uint32_t mTextureHeight;
        ITexture::TextureFormat mTextureFormat;
        ITexture::TextureType mTextureType;


        PackageTexture();
    };

    /* PackageMaterial definition */
    struct PackageMaterial
    {
        std::string mName;
        PackageTexture mDiffuseTexture;
        Vec3 mDiffuseColor;
        Vec3 mAmbientColor;
        Vec3 mSpecularColor;
        Vec3 mEmissiveColor;


        PackageMaterial();
    };

    /* PackageModel definition */
    struct PackageModel
    {
        std::string mName;
        std::vector<PackageModel> mChildren;
        std::vector<PackageMesh> mMeshes;
        Mat4 mTransform;


        PackageModel();
    };

    /* JonsPackage definition */
    struct JonsPackage
    {
        PackageHeader mHeader;
        std::vector<PackageModel> mModels;
        std::vector<PackageMaterial> mMaterials;


        JonsPackage();
    };
```

I am using Boost Serialization to save/load from the filesystem, which up untill now has been absolutely wonderous as it requires almost no code to do it.

However after importing some 3d models and then try to load it up again, the loading times are enormous; it takes almost 30 seconds to load from filesystem and then to deserialize.

This is the code to serialize/deserialize:

```
JonsPackagePtr ReadJonsPkg(const std::string& jonsPkgName)
    {
        std::ifstream jonsPkgStream(jonsPkgName.c_str(), std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);        // TODO: support opening of older resource packages
        JonsPackagePtr pkg(HeapAllocator::GetDefaultHeapAllocator().AllocateObject<JonsPackage>(), boost::bind(&HeapAllocator::DeallocateObject<JonsPackage>, &HeapAllocator::GetDefaultHeapAllocator(), _1));

        if (jonsPkgStream && jonsPkgStream.good() && jonsPkgStream.is_open())
        {
            std::stringstream buf(std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out);
            buf << jonsPkgStream.rdbuf();
            buf.seekg(0);
            jonsPkgStream.close();

            boost::archive::binary_iarchive iar(buf);

            iar >> (*pkg.get());
        }

        jonsPkgStream.close();

        return pkg;
    }

    bool WriteJonsPkg(const std::string& jonsPkgName, const JonsPackagePtr pkg)
    {
        std::ofstream outStream(jonsPkgName.c_str(), std::ios::out | std::ios::binary | std::ios::trunc);
        bool ret = false;

        if (outStream.is_open())
        {
            boost::archive::binary_oarchive oar(outStream);
            oar << (*pkg.get());

            ret = true;
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

Here is an image of the VS2012 performance analys:
http://postimg.org/image/smdsnu5gl/

The resource file I am using is about 26 MB on disc, contains 3 package models and 14 package textures. What could I possibly do about this, is my file format design a dead-end?

Answer (score 1):

This is too much time for only 26MB. I saw that you are running that in VS2012. I recommend you to try in release and run the program outside the VS2012 environment, just by clicking your .exe directly from the file explorer.

Also you do not need to load your whole file in memory to deserialize its contents.

You can try with the following code:

```
std::ifstream file("path.dat");
boost::archive::binary_iarchive iar(file);
```

Comment: Running outside of VS did the trick for me with the same problem. It was still attaching the debugger even in release which I didn't realize.